# SMPP check through MONIT

Tags: monit

I am new in linux and I need help to check SMPP binds of kannel through MONIT whether they are online or dead.
Currently in a script file named XYZ.sh using *(curl --silent http://localhost:xyz/status?password=abc | grep SMPP| grep -v online)* and writing in Monit as below :

```
check file XYZ with path /root/script/XYZ.sh if match "dead" after 5 cycles then alert
```

It is not working,please guide as i am very upset.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong check. You should use **process** instead of **file** when using custom scripts.

Also **process** is not able to check content so you have to return a different exit code according to the expected behaviour. So you will have to update your script to return an exit code according to your expectations

```
check program XYZ with path /root/script/XYZ.sh if status != 0 for 5 cycles then alert
```

Documentation: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Program